# Autocomplete not working over https laravel php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hello everyone please help me my auto complete functionality is not working over https connection it is working fine on localhost.
the problem is only the in set value in text box is not working
the on click method is not working kindly look and help me

input form

```
<input style="background-color:white;" value="{{input('sq')}}" name="sq" id="product-serach" class="form-control form-control-navbar"
```

type="text" placeholder="Search Here" aria-label="Search">

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#product-serach').keyup(function(){ 
        var query = $(this).val();
        if(query != '')
        {
         var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
         $.ajax({
           url:"{{ route('autocomplete.fetch') }}",
          method:"POST",
          data:{query:query, _token:_token},
          success:function(data){
           $('#product-serach-list').fadeIn();  
                    $('#product-serach-list').html(data);
          }
         });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#listitem', function(){  
        $('#product-serach').val($(this).text());  
        $('#product-serach-list').fadeOut();  
    });  

});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What error you are getting? Something you might be getting in your AJAX function. API will be getting triggered but then something will be happing.

Comment: hello first of all thanks for showing Interest to help Actually there is no error showing in console nothing shows. on click

Comment: Where are you in error handing in AJAX? ``error: function(err){console.log(err); }`` After the ``success: function(data){ //code },``  add that error handler.  Also check in **Network** Tab of your browser what is the status code you are getting?

Comment: there is no error in network data fetch the response is 200 in network . The only problem is when I click on list items that shown in image the items is not inserting in input field with this code:   $(document).on('click', '#listitem', function(){  
        $('#product-serach').val($(this).text());  
        $('#product-serach-list').fadeOut();  
    });

Comment: So you are getting the Data from your PHP? Use ``console.log(data)`` in **success** handler and check are you getting anything?

Comment: I am getting the data from php very well you can see in image I uploaded but the only on click functionality is not working. If I remove https from app then it says from is unsecured auto complete is off  with in MIXEDMATCH contents.

Comment: I solved there is jQuery file issue. Thanks